# Symfony2: option "validation_groups" does not exist

Tags: forms, validation, symfony

I'm trying to add validation group based on clicked button as described in [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#groups-based-on-the-clicked-button), but getting an exception

> "The option "validation_groups" does not exist. Known options are: "attr", "auto_initialize", "block_name", "disabled", "label", "translation_domain"".

And really, there is no such option in [submit field type](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/submit.html).

I'm completely lost, any ideas what it should look like?
Field is added in form type, not controller.

Symfony version - 2.3.4.

My form type

```
<?php

namespace Acme\FooBundle\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;

class MyFormType extends AbstractType {

    public function getName()
    {
       return 'myForm';
    }

     /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
         $builder
            ->add('firstName', 'text')
            ->add('lastName', 'text')
            ->add('mobilePhone', 'text')
            ->add('save', 'submit', [
                'validation_groups' => false,
            ])
        ;
    }
```

}

Comment: if you show the code that you are referring to, it would be much easier to see what's wrong

Comment: what is your sf version ? `Support for buttons in forms was introduced in Symfony 2.3.`

Comment: I already used a very similar code on my project with success (on a 2.3.x symfony). It's a bit strange. 
Are you sure that an external bundle doesn't override the native submit FormType ? 
Do you try to execute a full `composer update` on your project ?